# Is there a Google Plus Comments plugin ? (Like Facebook Social Comments, DISQUS or IntenseDebate)?

Tags: php, html, api, plugins, google-plus

I was wondering and trying to find a Google Plus plugin, like Facebook have, like DISQUS or IntenseDebate?

Anyone knows if there is one or have an idea of how to do one using Google+ API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
</script>
<div class="g-comments"
    data-href="http://stackoverflow.com"
    data-width="580"
    data-first_party_property="BLOGGER"
    data-view_type="FILTERED_POSTMOD">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fdyuhp90/1/

Without API Key

Comment: I was trying to implement this but with no luck. After pasting the code into the HTML file and changing the `href` argument to `window.location` the comment box loads fine but I can't add any comments. Console shows variuos POST errors while requesting `/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.comments_widget.en.50uyNOSkHIA.O/m=c_b/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=Ag/rs=AGL…`. I also can't add comments in your jsfiddle. Does this method still work? If not, is there any other straightforward solution?

Answer (score 2):

No official comments plugin exists at this time, but you can use the REST APIs to access comments that have been made on public posts via the [comments.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/comments/list) method.

This means that if you share a page on Google+ via a public activity, you can use the APIs to list all of the comments made to that activity on Google+ and then render them in your page. You can then link visitors to the activity thereby allowing them to participate in the conversation.

I've seen a few implementations of this technique. [Here](http://little418.com/2011/12/google-comments-on-your-static-html-blog.html) is a JavaScript implementation that's designed to drop into a static HTML blog. I won't reproduce the whole entry here, since it's pretty involved, but the gist of what you need to do is:

1. [Get an API key](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#apikey) to access the Google+ APIs
2. Embed the ID of the public activity into your document. In the linked example stashes it into the class of a div.
3. Use the JSONP interface of the REST APIs to fetch the comments for that activity. If one page of comments is sufficient, this is a one liner.

`https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/_somePublicActivityId_/comments?key=_yourApiKey_&callback=myawesomecallback`

1. From your callback function print the comments somewhere in the page.

   ```
   function myawesomecallback(resposneJson) {
     var activity = resposneJson.items[0].inReplyTo[0];
     var comments = resposneJson.items;

     //find element to insert into
     var insertionElements = document.getElementsByClassName('g-comments-for ' + activity.id);
     var insertionElement = insertionElements[0];

     var newContents = "";
     for(i=0; i<comments.length; i++) {
       var actor = comments[i].actor;

       var commentBody = comments[i].object.content;

       //do the insertion
       newContents += "<dt><a href='" + actor.url + 
         "'><img src='" + actor.image.url + "' /></a></dt>" + 
         "<dd><a href='" + actor.url + "'>" + actor.displayName + 
         "</a>: " + commentBody + "</dd>";
     }
     insertionElement.innerHTML = "<dl>" + newContents + 
       "</dl> <p class='g-commentlink'>Please comment on the <a href='" + 
       activity.url + "'>Google+ activity</a></p>";   
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

No, the [Google+ API is currently entirely read-only](https://developers.google.com/+/api/), and it doesn't have a comments plugin like Facebook does.